# Communication between two data grids

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, localconnection

I am trying to make connection between two datagrid in two separate windows.

Until now, I am able to create a datagrid in one FLEX browser window but got stuck furthur.

On some click event in one of 1st datagrid row-column field  value, (i.e itemRenderer in form of button), I want to open a new window (using some LocalConnection or ExternalInterface.call) to open another window with the part of the original data grid.

Is it possible to do so ? Which method should I use   - LocalConnection or ExternalInterface.call ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On some click event use [navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#navigateToURL%28%29) to launch your second browser window with your second application that contains the second DataGrid.

Once the two instances are up you can communicate between them using [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_13.html).